# How to update sdk using only aab or apk?

Tags: android, sdk, apk, android-app-bundle

Issue found:

> Violation of User Data, Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information Policies
> We have observed that your app is using an SDK that is designed to collect device location by default. This SDK can result in your app violating the prominent disclosure and consent and/or approved purpose requirements of Google Play’s User Data and Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policies. You are hereby requested to provide evidence of your compliance with the Prominent Disclosure and Consent requirements. Your app submissions will be rejected pending your action.
>
> Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> Version code 1000007:
> SDK: Startio com.startapp:inapp-sdk (consider upgrading to version 4.10.1)
> To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:
>
> Verify that your app accesses, collects, uses, and shares (including with SDKs) device location only for approved purposes and in compliance with the applicable prominent disclosure and consent requirements of the above-mentioned policies. Do not enable SDK data collection if it violates these requirements.
> Submit an appeal of this rejection and attach evidence (e.g. screenshots or a video demonstration of the in-app prominent disclosure and consent experience) of your compliance with the Prominent Disclosure requirements.
>
> In the alternative, you may consider removing the SDK code designed to collect personal and sensitive user data by default, or moving to an alternative SDK or version which includes the appropriate technical mechanism to ensure that end user consent information collected by apps is honored. You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK, if available from your SDK provider or removing the SDK. Google is unable to endorse or recommend any third party software.
> Startio com.startapp:inapp-sdk: Consider upgrading to version 4.10.1 of the SDK.

I tried direct opening via Android Studio but it doesn't display the gradle file

Comment: Your question seems to mainly contain text from Google Developer Console but no real question. Questions on why Google rejects apps are unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: Not related to Google console, need to update the sdk version of this  Startio com.startapp:inapp-sdk:

Comment: No, "consider upgrading to version 4.10.1" is just a suggestion that doesn't have anything to do with the actual problem. You have to declare at Google what privacy related data your app collects. And Google has identified that your privacy declaration does not match the app. So you have to remove the SDK that causes it or update the privacy declaration. That is what Google tells you in this section. Please just read it completly.